# If $E$ and $F$ are field, what is $E\vee F$?

Tags: notation, field-theory

If $E$ and $F$ are field, what is $E\vee F$ ? Let take for exemple $E=\mathbb Q(a)$ and $\mathbb Q(b)$. Do we have $$E\vee F=\mathbb Q(a,b) \ \ ?$$

Comment: What does $\vee$ mean?

Comment: good question, that's why I ask the question. In my course it's written that $E\vee F$ is the composition of the field $E$ and $F$, but that's all. I search on google, but nothing. May be it will help, the property of it is $$[E\vee F: K]=[E:K][F:K]$$ if $\gcd([E:K],[F:K])=1$.

Comment: Two fields of different characteristics can't embed in a same field so you may want to specify $\chi_E = \chi_F$.

Answer (score 1):

I expect $\lor$ is to be interpreted as join, which is to say $E \lor F$ is the least (with least being intepreted in terms of $\subseteq$) field containing both $E$ and $F$. I am willing to be corrected though.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't $E$ and $F$ subfields of a same field $k$? Then $E \vee_k F$ would be the intersection of all subfields of $k$ containing both $E$ and $F$.

Else, I am not sure there is a smallest field containing any two fields of same characteristic, nor am I sure there always is a field containing them.

Maybe others can correct me.